# Custom Splashscreen and Icon in Ionic 2 not showing, Cordova Icons showing

Tags: cordova, ionic2, splash-screen

I don't understand why my icon and splash screen aren't showing. They are properly referenced in the config.xml file but instead it's the cordova default images that show. Please help

EDIT:
I just noticed that the icons and splash screens generated were not copied into their respective platforms. Why did this happen?

Comment: what is your custom splash screen image pixel.

Comment: it is 2208 x 2208

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check out this link: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1608 and specifically florentsuc's comment

i solved it by running: ionic platform remove android ionic platform add android@6.1.0

Answer (score 5):

To Modify splash screen you can go to `resources` folder and modify the 
`icon.png` and `splash.png`

You can run `ionic resources` command to generate resources for current installed platforms.

It is imperative that you keep icon and splash sizes and format the same or it will not work.

Also make sure you have your platforms installed before doing this:

```
ionic platform add android

ionic platform add iOS
```

Splashscreen:

- You can get a template [here](http://code.ionicframework.com/resources/splash.psd)
- 2208x2208 px
- .png format

Icon:

- You can get a template [here](http://code.ionicframework.com/resources/icon.psd)
- 192x192 px
- .png format

I also realized its best too keep these images small, as soon as they go higher than 35mb they take longer to generate

Comment: hey, my icons and splashscreens are being generated fine, they aren't just showing up in respective platforms. Cordova images are showing instead.

Comment: @ifeoluwakingTry removing your platforms ionic platform remove ios,  then add the again, ionic platform add iOS

Answer (score 3):

This issue is caused by the res map not being created in the correct location. Running the following string of commands will remedy your issue.

```
mv platforms/android/res/{values,xml} res
rm -rf platforms/android/res
cp -r res platforms/android
ionic build android
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is what I did:

- Make the icon.png and splash.png and put in resources folder.
- Run ionic resources command (and automatically ionic made all the files).
- Run ionic platform remove android.
- Run ionic platform add android (and the config.xml file was updated).
- I changed manually the android/res/.../screen.png and android/res/.../icon.png files with the generated before.

And finally my custom icon and splash screen appeared.

In other words you have to update the files manually in platforms/android and platform/ios.